# How to get an OnClick Event in Unity to action?

Tags: unity, c#

I am new to Game Dev and I am following a [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_99shHk-hM&list=PLZ1b66Z1KFKgp-sjQ8ldU3eh8DoQ3a14P&index=8).  Within this tutorial, we create a quest system, that allows you to accept or decline a quest. This tutorial is based on Unity 5 and I am using 2020.1 so there could be version differences that could be causing the issue.

I have a script called:

**Quest001Buttons.cs**

```
public class Quest001Buttons : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject ThePlayer;
    public GameObject NoticeCam;
    public GameObject UIQuest;
    public GameObject ActiveQuestBox;
    public GameObject Objective01;
    public GameObject Objective02;
    public GameObject Objective03;

    public void AcceptQuest() {
        Debug.Log("Accept Registered");
        ThePlayer.SetActive(true);
        NoticeCam.SetActive(false);
        UIQuest.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine(SetQuestUi());
    }

    IEnumerator SetQuestUi() {

        ActiveQuestBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "My First Weapon";
        Objective01.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Reach the Clearing";
        Objective02.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Open Chest";
        Objective03.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Get Weapon";
        QuestManager.ActiveQuestNumber = 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        ActiveQuestBox.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Objective01.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        Objective02.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        Objective03.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(9);
        ActiveQuestBox.SetActive(false);
        Objective01.SetActive(false);
        Objective02.SetActive(false);
        Objective03.SetActive(false);

    }
}
```

I have an Empty GameObject called "QuestButtonManager" which I have assigned the above script to.
I also have a UI GamObject called "Accept" and I have attached the QuestButtonManager GameObject to the OnClick() Event within that component.  I have selected:
"Runtime Only" and the function of "Quest001Buttons.AcceptQuest".

When I run the game and press the Accept Button...the game seems to not function after that and is stuck on that screen, with the button highlighted...not even the `Debug.Log` text is printed in the console.

Any help is greatly appreciated before I give it up and look for a more updated version to learn on.

Comment: That video is over a half hour long. Can you point us to the section which is actually relevant for this question? YouTube allows you to create a link to the middle of a video by right-clicking and selecting "copy video URL at this position".

Comment: Here is the link to the point where I was following along and did not get the same result [link] (https://youtu.be/m_99shHk-hM?list=PLZ1b66Z1KFKgp-sjQ8ldU3eh8DoQ3a14P&t=1015)

Comment: Is your button in a Canvas? Is there an EventSystem in the scene? Did you do anything with the default setting of either which could break things?

Comment: @Philipp The button is within a canvas. There is an EventSystem, but not sure what the defaults are supposed to be.  The Event System does not have a GameObject assigned to "First Selected" .  It also has "Standalone Input Module" component, with carious axis etc...but no idea what this is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to resolve the issue and to understand why it was doing what it was doing. I removed the script component, copied the code within and deleted the script.  I closed down VS2019 and created a new script, pasted the code and re-added the component.

I did try to Remove the component and re-add first, but that had no affect.

Not sure why closing down VS2019 and re-creating the script worked, perhaps VS2019 was returning a cached script and did not have the full code..though it was showing the correct code in the inspector.

If anyone else has a similar issue, it maybe the integration of VS2017/2019 with Unity that could cause issues.